# Tefillin for somone missing fingers

Tags: tefilin, handicap-disabled-impair

If someone is missing the middle finger of their non-dominant hand, how would they wear tefillin?  Just skip the 3 wraps around the middle finger?  Wrap 3 times around another finger?

Comment: See Menachos 37a

Comment: I wonder if the finger wrapping is so important that they would suggest putting tefillin on the other arm?

Answer (score 4):

If one is missing his middle finger, he should wrap around the finger closest to the thumb, the index finger. That is the same finger a ring is placed on by marriage, and the wrappings represent our connection to Hashem [as we say "וארשתיך"].

(שו"ת בית ישראל  מהאב"ד דעדעלין או"ח סי' ג)

Comment: @פריזהב Excellent! Much more memorable indeed!